# Generation of a stream of data bits 0s and 1s at a certain bit or data rate

Tags: digital-communications

This is a very basic question ,but basics important, : How is a stream of data bits (zeros and ones that express a certain information) and at a certain rate being generated? what is involved in terms of processing and possibly hardware?  a clock? a quantizer? a sampler? or what exactly?  I really would like to get a brief idea

Comment: UART.  universal asynchronous receiver transceiver.

Comment: Can you inform us in which context you're asking this? Basically, the central theorem on which all information theory is based, is that you can represent *any* finite amount of information as bits. So, anything that yields a constant rate of information is a fixed-rate data source of bits. That can be something as simple as a coin flipped every 10s, or a camera producing uncompressed video, or a hardware random number generator, or a geiger counter, or …

Comment: I basically want to know what is involved, so take for example an uncompressed video, what is involved (very briefly) in converting the video information into bits that are generated at a certain rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multimedia signals such as video,picture, music, speech have bandwidths associated with their baseband analog source nature.

For digital processing this *bandlimited* analog source is passed through a **analog to digital converter** (into a sequence of samples), which operates at a clock-frequency determined by the signal **sampling rate**, $F_s$, which is also limited by the source bandwidth due to Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem.

Furthermore for each sample, a number of **bits** are used to **quantize** (numerically resolve) it. The number of bits is dictated by the signal amplitude accuracy requirement. For digital video, it's mostly 8-bits per RGB channel. Or for audio it can be 16-bits per stereo L/R channel.

Hence, the multiplication of samlping rate $F_s$ and bit-per-sample gives you the raw source bit rate $R_b$. You may prefer to apply some statistical or perceptual data compression to reduce $R_b$ to a minimum.

Then you choose a digital **modulation** scheme such as FSK,PSK,GMSK,OFDM... and transmit those bits through your favorite medium. Before doing this, you may increse $R_b$ (by adding redundancies) for channel transmission error correction purposes. The result is your bit-stream (not necessarily logic signal levels of 0s and 1s though) that's traveling accross the universe...

I hope I clarified it.